# Android display search results approach

Tags: android, load

I want to display search result on the screen, i have implemented in such a way that.

From the search form user fill the 'search field' and 'search location' i set values into bean and that bean is static so that i can access it from every where.

Then i start search result screen intent using

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SearchVenueResults.this, SearchResults.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

on the 'SearchResults' activity 'oncreate' method i load data on the behalf of static bean which values filled from search form and then display data.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        loadDataAndSetupUI();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

My question is is it the correct approach to use it or in Android there is another preferable approach ?

any quick idea or quick code is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, generally, the `onCreate` handler of your result screen activity is definitely a good place to do this. However, reading between the lines of your question, there are at least two things I noticed which may cause problems:

First, using a static object to transport values from one activity to another is definitely the wrong approach. That's because for one, there already is a well defined mechanism in Android for exchanging data between contexts, and that's via [Bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). So, to tell your result activity about the things your user is searching for, do something like this:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SearchVenueResults.this, SearchResults.class);
mainIntent.putExtra("search_query", getValueFromSearchBox());
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

In your SearchResults activity, do this in onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String searchQuery = getIntent().getExtras().getStringExtra("search_query");
    loadDataAndSetupUI(searchQuery);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Moreover, Android behaves pretty much unpredictable with respect to the life-time of static variables. I noticed several times that maintaining a static variable in an activity class does *not* guarantee that this variable is still valid when launching a new activity, so you should never rely on statics as a means of exchanging data between classes.

Second, you most definitely don't want to implement `loadDataAndSetupUI` to run synchronously. Doing so will lock up your UI until the search has terminated, and Android may even decide to kill your app. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for background jobs instead.